# Additionally ... also

Tags: redundancy

[disclosure: I'm not a native speaker of English]

I work as a university professor. When writing up lecture notes as well as research papers, I have a tendency to write things like the following.

> A Monte Carlo simulation shows that Factor A is a significant one. Additionally, it also shows that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case.

The question is whether the *Additionally...also* sequence is a stylistically acceptable one, given that both *additionally* and *also* convey additivity. I keep on using it because using just one of the two sounds weird, in a way that I really can't put my finger on (but then, this might be because I don't speak English natively).

If *Additionally...also* is deprecated, I would welcome suggestions of alternative ways of expressing the same meaning.

Comment: Are you wishing to use 'additionally' in the sentence-connector comment role, along with 'also' in the 'it shows X – and Y –' role? Switching thus: 'A Monte Carlo simulation shows that Factor A is a significant one. I might add that it also shows that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case.' differentiates the usages more clearly, but is fairly informal. I'd just drop the 'additionally' here.

Comment: I do agree that one is redundant, but I think what makes it sound "weird" is that it doesn't have as much emphasis just using one or the other. Medica's sentence "The simulation also shows..." (repeating the subject) is good because it gives emphasis that "Additionally, ..." seems to lack. Formally, just go with one; informally, both together are fine. Note one would probably emphasise the "also" in speaking when using both together.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that *additionally...also* appears redundant, although it *can* be used appropriately when you're saying, essentially, that *in addition to the aforementioned, they show xyz as well.* However, a single *also* or *in addition* is not strange to my native AmE ears. In most cases, therefore, I would avoid that construction.

This Ngram shows how much more frequent *In addition* is than *Additionally* to start a sentence.

[image]

So, you can write

> *The simulation also shows* that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case. or *In addition*, it shows..."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with medica's recommendation that you either (1) use "In addition" rather than than "Additionally" at the beginning of the sentence and omit "also," or (2) omit "In addition" (and "Additionally") from the beginning of the sentence and retain "also."

Another option is to begin the second sentence with "Also," although some style mavens—and some publishing houses that follow their dictates—disapprove of this tactic (for reasons I've never fully understood):

> A Monte Carlo simulation shows that Factor A is significant. **Also**, it shows that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case.

If you want to vary your wording beyond the trio of "in addition," "additionally," and "also" in such situations, you have several other alternatives. One approach is to begin the sentence with "Moreover," "Further," or "Furthermore," omitting the "also" in each case:

> A Monte Carlo simulation shows that Factor A is significant. **Moreover/Further/Furthermore**, it shows that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case.

Yet another approach is to omit the "also" and add "too" or "as well" in an appropriate Ilocation:

> A Monte Carlo simulation shows that Factor A is significant. It shows, **too/as well**, that the outliers can be grouped together as a special case.